# How to get the minimum crop-able dimension of an image using PHP with aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I am looking to limit the minimum width and height of the cropping selection area in aspect ratio, so that the user cannot take a very very small section of an image.

For example user uploaded image of width = 602px and height = 400px in that case what would be minimum cropping selection area?

according to Google+ minimum cropable selection area width = 574px and height = 323px user can't make it smaller than this dimension.

what logic would be ?

FYI above logic i'm looking for crop cover photo like Google plus

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long waiting i applied simply logic and it works for me as aspected.

```
var min_crop_width = (Original_Width / 100) * 83.5; // Minimum percentage
var min_crop_height = (min_crop_width / 5) * 1; // Your Standard Ratio...
min_crop_width = (min_crop_height * 5) / 1; // Your Standard Ratio...
```

Thanks!